# SplitSeries does not work in Packed Bubble Highchart in r

Tags: r, highcharts

I need to have a split packed bubble chart in r (highchart). I do not get a split. "SplitSeries" in hc_plotOptions does not work.

Hello there!

I need to have a split packed bubble chart in r like this one: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/packed-bubble-split.

I've written a code, which does not provide the result I want. In particular, "SplitSeries" does not work. I do not get a split.

Here is the full code:

```
value <- 50
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'packedbubble') %>%
  hc_title(text = 'Steuerabzüge', align = 'center') %>%
  hc_tooltip(useHTML = T, pointFormat = '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.description}') %>%
  hc_plotOptions(packedbubble = list(
    minSize = '20%',
    maxSize = '50%',
    zMin = 0,
    zMax = 1000,
    layoutAlgorithm = list(
      gravitationalConstant = 0.10,
      splitSeries = T,
      seriesInteraction = F,
      dragBetweenSeries = T,
      parentNodeLimit = T
    )
  )
  ) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = T) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = T) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Standardberufsauslagen', data = list(
    list(name = 'Fahrkostenabzug', 
         value = value, 
         description = 'Anweisungen'), 
    list(name = 'Fahrrad/Kleinmotorad',
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen'), 
    list(name = 'Kosten für auswärtige Verpflegung', 
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen'),
    list(name = 'Übrige Berufskosten', 
         value =value,
         description = 'Anweisungen'),
    list(name = 'Aus- und Weiterbildungskosten', 
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen'),
    list(name = 'Auslagen für Nebenerwerb',
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen')
  )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Vorsorge', data = list(
    list(name = 'Einkauf in 2. Säule', 
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen'),
    list(name = 'Einkauf in Säule 3a', 
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen')
  )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'Vorsorge', data = list(
    list(name = 'Einkauf in 2. Säule', 
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen'),
    list(name = 'Einkauf in Säule 3a', 
         value = value,
         description = 'Anweisungen')
  )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for this moment because current highcharter uses Highcharts 7.0.1, but nested packed bubbles exist since Highcharts 7.1.0 version.

See the changelog here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v7.1.0

Or API here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.packedbubble.layoutAlgorithm.splitSeries

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your promt reply! :) Do I understand correctly that I just need to wait till highcharter will start using 7.1.0 version an that at this moment there is nothing else to do with this issue? Sorry for a dummy question, I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait for highcharter new version release. Split series in packed bubbles is very hard to implement in JavaScript and nearly impossible in R. Waiting for a new Highcharter is the best solution. You can contact Highcharter author and ask when will he release a new version.